# Exclude 0's while random number generation using base sample

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyr, purrr

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
  id    shift_back shift_forward
  <chr>      <dbl>         <dbl>
1 11          -140             0
2 12           -63           149
3 13           -37           327
4 14             0           193
5 16           -30            30
6 17           -30            30
7 18           -30            30
8 19           -30            30
```

I would like to generate a random number with these columns `shift_back` and `shift_forward` as range interval.

However, I don't want the random number to be `0`.

The below code works fine but includes 0 as well

```
mutate(shift = base::sample(seq(shift_back, shift_forward, by = 1), 1))
```

However, this produces an output like below which can have `0` as shift value as well

[image]

How can I produce a random number within the range but excluding 0 (from the interval). Basically I don't want the shift value to be 0 (zero).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can exclude zeros before sampling.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>% 
  mutate(shift = seq(shift_back, shift_forward) %>% .[. != 0] %>% sample(1))
```

Comment: Hi , may I check with you what does the outer and inner dot indicate in `.[.!=0]`?

Comment: @TheGreat Actually, `seq(a, b) %>% .[. != 0]` is equivalent to `seq(a, b)[seq(a, b) != 0]`. Because `seq(a, b)` appears twice, I move it to the front of a pipe and the `"."` behind the pipe represents it.

Comment: can help me with this?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563903/use-of-mutate-in-summarise-function-using-r

Answer (score 2):

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  id = 11:14,
  shift_back = c(-140, -63, -37, 0),
  shift_forward = c(0,149, 327, 193)
)

df %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(shift = list(seq(shift_back, shift_forward, by = 1)),
         shift = list(shift[shift != 0]),
         shift = sample(shift, 1))
```

Comment: You name the new column `shift` but call `vctr`, which get an error *"object 'vctr' not found"*.

Comment: can help me with this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63563903/use-of-mutate-in-summarise-function-using-r